# UltraVNC and ODBC Data Source Administrator

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, ultravnc

I have run into a rather strange problem. I use `UltraVNC` to connect to a `Windows 7` workstation, and for most of the time it works great; however, as soon as I open (by "running": `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`) the `ODBC Data Source Administrator`, I am unable to click on anything.

Once this happens I can connect using `Remote Desktop Connection`, close the `UltraVNC Server`, restart the `UltraVNC Server`, finish my work, close the `RDP` connection, and then reconnect using `UltraNVC`.

When I end the `RDP` connection it logs out of the Windows account, so that when I connect with `UltraVNC` I am at the windows account login screen. I click on the account I want to log in to, and everything freezes for a couple minutes, and then everything works how it is supposed to.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening, how to fix it, or what a more elegant solution is?

Comment: It sounds to me like `odbcad32.exe` is running as an Administrator and UltraVNC is unable to interact with it due to elevation issues.

Comment: Why are you starting odbcad32.exe instead of UltraVNC?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure what you're asking. I am using `UltraVNC` to connect to the computer, and am then running the application `odbcad32.exe`. I think @Michael Frank is right in suggesting it has something to do with being run as an Administrator.